# CRUD working except update (PHP) and no error shown , and tshows that its modified but no changes

Tags: php, mysql, crud

all of the crud functions work except the update one, and no error is shown. After the user clicks update button it shows the ticket's details, this is the code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include 'connection.php';
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Ticket Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div class="container mt-5">

        <?php include('msg.php'); ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4>Ticket Edit 
                            <a href="homepage.php" class="btn btn-danger float-end">BACK</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['id']))
                        {
                            $ticket_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id='$ticket_id' ";
                            $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
                            {
                                $ticket = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);
                                ?>
                                <form action="crud.php" method="POST">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ticket_id" value="<?= $ticket['id']; ?>">

                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label>Username</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?=$ticket['username'];?>" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label>Titre</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="titre" value="<?=$ticket['titre'];?>" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label>Probleme</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="probleme" value="<?=$ticket['probleme'];?>" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <label>Etat</label>
            
                                        <input type="radio" name="ouvert" value="<?=$ticket['etat'];?>"><label for="">Ouvert</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="ferme" value="<?=$ticket['etat'];?>"><label for="">Ferme</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="resolu" value="<?=$ticket['etat'];?>"><label for="">Resolu</label><br>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3">
                                        <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">
                                            Update Ticket
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                                <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo "<h4>No Such Id Found</h4>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

after clicking the submit button:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

$ticket_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);

$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
$titre=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['titre']);
$probleme=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['probleme']);
$etat=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['etat']);

$query="UPDATE tickets SET username='$username', titre='$titre' , probleme='$probleme', etat='$etat' WHERE id='$ticket_id' ";
$query_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if($query_run){
    $_SESSION['msg']="Ticket modifie";
    header("location: homepage.php");
    exit(0);
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg']="Ticket n'est pas modifie";
    header("location: affichage.php");
    exit(0);
}
}
?>
```

it is shown that the query ran but there are no changes and drives directly to the homepage as if it was updates.
i am still a beginner

Comment: try using prepared statements instead. They provide extra help in checking that the variables are of the right type, and protect  against SQL injection attacks

Comment: With your `header("location"...)` statements you move away from your crud.php page very quickly after your `mysqli_query()` call. Either to homepage.php or to affichage.php. This makes it impossible to look at any error message you might have received from the MySQL update statement. Also make sure to have activated all error messages in PHP during debugging with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your $query string is incorrect.  The string is a SQL/MySQL command which the database engine will process.  The SQL/MySQL command is a mixture of string data of things like UPDATE, name of table, SET, element names (username, titre, probleme, etat, id), etc along with the PHP variables that are being updated as the content of the elements.  The SQL/MySQL syntax calls for the element content to be surrounded by single or double quotes (you are using single quotes because you're using double quotes to mark the constant (non-PHP variable) portion of your string.  As you build your $query string you have to add strings and PHP variables together using standard PHP rules (the ".").  If you were building the code to update a element named animal then you would do something like "animal=' " . $variable . "' ". If $variable's value was "cat", then that part of the database command would be  "animal='cat' ".

See example below:

```
$query="UPDATE tickets SET username='" . $username . "', titre='" . $titre . "' , probleme='" . $probleme . "', etat='" . $etat . "' WHERE id='" . $ticket_id . "' ";
```